# How clang choose to generate elf header rodata from defined array macro

Tags: c, clang, llvm, elf, ebpf

I reported an issue in https://github.com/cilium/cilium/issues/18616#issuecomment-1021576627 that when the macro `VTEP_ENDPOINT` exceed `2` members

```
#define ENABLE_VTEP 1
#define VTEP_ENDPOINT (__u32[]){0xec48a90a, 0xee48a90a, 0x1f48a90a, 0x2048a90a, }
#define VTEP_MAC (__u64[]){0x562e984c3682, 0x582e984c3682, 0x5eaaed93fdf2, 0x5faaed93fdf2, }
#define VTEP_NUMS 4
```

clang will generate an BPF backend elf object file with
`.rodata.cst32` in elf header that Linux kernel BPF BTF does not support

```
[21] .rodata.cst32     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00011e68.
```

oddly, if I reduce the `VTEP_ENDPOINT` array macro member to be `<=2` like

```
#define VTEP_ENDPOINT (__u32[]){0xec48a90a, 0xee48a90a,  }
```

no `.rodata.cst32` will be generated by clang, I don't understand why clang would do this, and I have no idea where I can dig into to find out the reason, any guidance or help are appreciated!

here is the PR commit for cilium that reference the code
https://github.com/cilium/cilium/pull/17370/commits/86bac3c5bcf7272d436a405705f375f779711978

```
diff --git a/bpf/Makefile b/bpf/Makefile
index c1fbd348c4..f4e3485154 100644
--- a/bpf/Makefile
+++ b/bpf/Makefile
@@ -133,6 +133,11 @@ MAX_OVERLAY_OPTIONS = $(MAX_BASE_OPTIONS) -DENCAP_IFINDEX=1 -DTUNNEL_MODE=1
 ifneq ("$(KERNEL)","49")
 MAX_OVERLAY_OPTIONS += -DLB_SELECTION=1 -DLB_SELECTION_MAGLEV=1
 endif
+ifeq ("$(KERNEL)","54")
+MAX_OVERLAY_OPTIONS+= -DENABLE_VTEP=1
+else ifeq ("$(KERNEL)","netnext")
+MAX_OVERLAY_OPTIONS+= -DENABLE_VTEP=1
+endif
 endif
 
 bpf_overlay.ll: bpf_overlay.c $(LIB)
@@ -266,6 +271,11 @@ MAX_LXC_OPTIONS = $(MAX_BASE_OPTIONS) -DENCAP_IFINDEX=1 -DTUNNEL_MODE=1
 ifneq (,$(filter $(KERNEL),"54" "netnext"))
 MAX_LXC_OPTIONS += -DENABLE_EGRESS_GATEWAY=1
 endif
+ifeq ("$(KERNEL)","54")
+MAX_LXC_OPTIONS+= -DENABLE_VTEP=1
+else ifeq ("$(KERNEL)","netnext")
+MAX_LXC_OPTIONS+= -DENABLE_VTEP=1
+endif
 endif
 
 bpf_lxc.ll: bpf_lxc.c $(LIB)
diff --git a/bpf/bpf_lxc.c b/bpf/bpf_lxc.c
index 2480b1ff44..16fca9f4f4 100644
--- a/bpf/bpf_lxc.c
+++ b/bpf/bpf_lxc.c
@@ -525,6 +525,7 @@ static __always_inline int handle_ipv4_from_lxc(struct __ctx_buff *ctx,
        __be32 orig_dip;
        __u32 __maybe_unused tunnel_endpoint = 0;
        __u8 __maybe_unused encrypt_key = 0;
+       mac_t __maybe_unused vtep_mac = 0;
        __u32 monitor = 0;
        __u8 ct_ret;
        bool hairpin_flow = false; /* endpoint wants to access itself via service IP */
@@ -830,6 +831,26 @@ ct_recreate4:
 skip_egress_gateway:
 #endif
 
+#ifdef ENABLE_VTEP
+       {
+               int i;
+
+               for (i = 0; i < VTEP_NUMS; i++) {
+                       if (tunnel_endpoint == VTEP_ENDPOINT[i]) {
+                               vtep_mac = VTEP_MAC[i];
+                               break;
+                       }
+               }
+
+               if (vtep_mac && tunnel_endpoint) {
+                       if (eth_store_daddr(ctx, (__u8 *)&vtep_mac, 0) < 0)
+                               return DROP_WRITE_ERROR;
+                       return __encap_and_redirect_with_nodeid(ctx, tunnel_endpoint,
+                                                                       WORLD_ID, monitor);
+               }
+       }
+#endif
+
 #ifdef TUNNEL_MODE
 # ifdef ENABLE_WIREGUARD
        /* In the tunnel mode we encapsulate pod2pod traffic only via Wireguard
diff --git a/bpf/bpf_overlay.c b/bpf/bpf_overlay.c
index 06cd5465e4..be5fd76cd5 100644
--- a/bpf/bpf_overlay.c
+++ b/bpf/bpf_overlay.c
@@ -204,6 +204,27 @@ static __always_inline int handle_ipv4(struct __ctx_buff *ctx, __u32 *identity)
 
                if (*identity == HOST_ID)
                        return DROP_INVALID_IDENTITY;
+#ifdef ENABLE_VTEP
+               {
+                       struct remote_endpoint_info *info;
+                       int i;
+                       bool is_vtep = false;
+
+                       info = lookup_ip4_remote_endpoint(ip4->saddr);
+                       if (!info)
+                               return DROP_NO_TUNNEL_ENDPOINT;
+                       for (i = 0; i < VTEP_NUMS; i++) {
+                               if (info->tunnel_endpoint == VTEP_ENDPOINT[i]) {
+                                       is_vtep = true;
+                                       break;
+                               }
+                       }
+                       if (is_vtep) {
+                               if (*identity != WORLD_ID)
+                                       return DROP_INVALID_VNI;
+                       }
+               }
+#endif
        }
 
        cilium_dbg(ctx, DBG_DECAP, key.tunnel_id, key.tunnel_label);
diff --git a/bpf/lib/common.h b/bpf/lib/common.h
index 284a17acac..99f7295b71 100644
--- a/bpf/lib/common.h
+++ b/bpf/lib/common.h
@@ -437,6 +437,7 @@ enum {
 #define DROP_PROXY_UNKNOWN_PROTO       -180
 #define DROP_POLICY_DENY       -181
 #define DROP_VLAN_FILTERED     -182
+#define DROP_INVALID_VNI       -183
 
 #define NAT_PUNT_TO_STACK      DROP_NAT_NOT_NEEDED
 
diff --git a/bpf/node_config.h b/bpf/node_config.h
index f9937224cd..43244b5f04 100644
--- a/bpf/node_config.h
+++ b/bpf/node_config.h
@@ -176,6 +176,18 @@ DEFINE_IPV6(HOST_IP, 0xbe, 0xef, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0xa, 0x
 # define LB_SELECTION          LB_SELECTION_RANDOM
 #endif
 
+#ifdef ENABLE_VTEP
+#define VTEP_ENDPOINT (__u32[]){0xeb48a90a, 0xec48a90a, 0xed48a90a, 0xee48a90a, }
+/* HEX representation of VTEP IP
+ * 10.169.72.235, 10.169.72.236, 10.169.72.237, 10.169.72.238
+ */
+#define VTEP_MAC (__u64[]){0x562e984c3682, 0x552e984c3682, 0x542e984c3682, 0x532e984c3682}
+/* VTEP MAC address
+ * 82:36:4c:89:2e:56, 82:36:4c:89:2e:55, 82:36:4c:89:2e:54, 82:36:4c:89:2e:53
+ */
+#define VTEP_NUMS 4
+#endif
+
 /* It appears that we can support around the below number of prefixes in an
  * unrolled loop for LPM CIDR handling in older kernels along with the rest of
  * the logic in the datapath, hence the defines below. This number was arrived
diff --git a/pkg/monitor/api/drop.go b/pkg/monitor/api/drop.go
index 4b79bf3322..f0e3ac5317 100644
--- a/pkg/monitor/api/drop.go
+++ b/pkg/monitor/api/drop.go
@@ -78,6 +78,7 @@ var errors = map[uint8]string{
        180: "Proxy redirection not supported for protocol",
        181: "Policy denied by denylist",
        182: "VLAN traffic disallowed by VLAN filter",
+       183: "Incorrect VNI from VTEP",
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the site where you use it?

Comment: @CarlNorum sorry what site? :-) I had the issue reported in Cilium github repo, and a PR feature I am developing to use the Macro https://github.com/cilium/cilium/pull/17370

Comment: "the site" as in "the place within your code"

Comment: I see, here is the site that reference the code https://github.com/cilium/cilium/pull/17370/commits/86bac3c5bcf7272d436a405705f375f779711978

Comment: I also updated the question with the complete code